# Sum of numbers at vertex/face of cube

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A cube has numbers ±1 placed at each vertex and each center of cube’s six faces
(so 14 numbers altogether). Moreover, it is known that each number in the center of a square
face equals to the product of the 4 numbers at the vertices of this face. Can the sum of all 14
numbers be equal to zero?

My first thoughts were test out some combinations and look for a pattern, but I was not able to notice anything major about it. So, the only progress I was able to really make was breaking it down into $V_1*V_2*V_3*V_4$, and so on for each face. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The values are only one and minus one so it shouldn't be that hard to do this.

Comment: @JohnDouma:  and the product relationship says you only have to assign the corners and compute the centers.  There are only $2^8=256$ possibilities even if you don't reduce for symmetry.

Comment: @RossMillikan I wasn't suggesting that all possibilities be tried. I thought I had a solution with only two $-1$s but I added wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Replace $+1$ by $0$, $-1$ by $1$ and the product by addition in $\mathbb F_2$. Then each vertex is used in the sum of exactly three faces, so the sum of all replaced numbers (in $\mathbb Z$) is $4$ times the sum of vertex numbers, so must be even. But the configuration sought in the original problem with sum zero must have exactly seven $1$ and seven $0$ bits upon replacement, leading to an odd sum in $\mathbb Z$. Thus no admissible configuration exists.

Comment: If you put $-1$ on opposite diagonals then all faces will have a product of $-1$ which leads to a sum of $-6$. There are eight vertices and only two of them are $-1$ so they sum up to $6$. Adding them gives $0$. Have I missed something?

Comment: @JohnDouma That would lead to a sum of $2$ in the original problem.

Comment: Yes, I added wrong.